# PHP: How to call oci_execute multiple times with different parameter values?

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I have an Oracle procedure that I need to call 3 times.  The procedure expects 5 parameters.  3 of the parameters will have the same value each time, while the other 2 will have different values for each execution.  How do I change the parameter values before each call to `oci_execute`?

Here is an what I have now:

```
$sql = "BEGIN
    pkg.DoSomething(p_first => :p_first,
        p_second => :p_second,
        p_third => :p_third,
        p_fourth => :p_fourth,
        p_fifth => :p_fifth);
    COMMIT;
    END;";

$statement = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
oci_bind_by_name($statement, ":p_first", $one);
oci_bind_by_name($statement, ":p_second", $two);
oci_bind_by_name($statement, ":p_third", $three);

$fourthVals = array("a", "b", "c");
$fifthVals = array("x", "y", "z");

for ($index = 0; $index < 3; $index++) {
    oci_bind_by_name($statement, ":p_fourth", $fourthVals[$index]);
    oci_bind_by_name($statement, ":p_fifth", $fifthVals[$index]);

    oci_execute($statement, OCI_DEFAULT);
}
```

When I execute it this way, the procedure throws the following error:

> PHP Warning:  oci_execute() [function.oci-execute]: ORA-20100: ::Period is missing.::

Period is the fourth parameter, so the error message indicates that the fourth value is not getting set.

Is this the correct way to change parameter values for each iteration?

Comment: Did you have any more input? Answers worked didn't work etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to bind once to a variable (since they are passed by reference), change the value of the variable and execute multiple times:

```
oci_bind_by_name($statement, ":p_fourth", $fourth);
oci_bind_by_name($statement, ":p_fifth", $fifth);

for ($index = 0; $index < 3; $index++) {
    $fourth = $fourthVals[$index];
    $fifth  = $fifthVals[$index];
    oci_execute($statement, OCI_DEFAULT);
}
```

I would expect some sort of *Only variables can be passed by reference* error for your first 3 `oci_bind_by_name` calls since you are passing a literal string and not a variable.

Comment: There is danger doing this kind of pattern in general if the data lengths change.

Comment: I have no idea what that means.

Comment: This approach worked, coupled with using variables rather than hard-coded values for other parameters.  Also, I need to specify the data type for a couple of the parameters which were floats, not strings.  Thanks!

Comment: If you use this approach there is a risk  you may end up with truncated data.

Comment: So, still what does that mean and how do you avoid it?  If you define a column as length 255 and try and insert more then it is truncated.  What are you getting at?

Answer (score -1):

Your code looks good to me.  Check how your PL/SQL actually uses the values passed in.

I created the schema:

```
drop table mytab;
create table mytab (first varchar2(6), second varchar2(6), third varchar2(6), fourth varchar2(6), fifth varchar2(6));

create or replace procedure DoSomething(p_first varchar2, p_second varchar2, p_third varchar2, p_fourth varchar2, p_fifth varchar2) as
begin
  insert into mytab values (p_first, p_second, p_third, p_fourth, p_fifth);
  commit;
end;
/
show errors
```

And ran your PHP code:

```
$one = 'A1';
$two = 'B2';
$three = 'C3';

$sql = "BEGIN
    DoSomething(p_first => :p_first,
        p_second => :p_second,
        p_third => :p_third,
        p_fourth => :p_fourth,
        p_fifth => :p_fifth);
    COMMIT;
    END;";

$statement = oci_parse($c, $sql);
oci_bind_by_name($statement, ":p_first", $one);
oci_bind_by_name($statement, ":p_second", $two);
oci_bind_by_name($statement, ":p_third", $three);

$fourthVals = array("a", "b", "c");
$fifthVals = array("x", "y", "z");

for ($index = 0; $index < 3; $index++) {
    oci_bind_by_name($statement, ":p_fourth", $fourthVals[$index]);
    oci_bind_by_name($statement, ":p_fifth", $fifthVals[$index]);

    oci_execute($statement, OCI_DEFAULT);
}
```

The table now contained:

```
SQL> select * from mytab;

FIRST  SECOND THIRD  FOURTH FIFTH
------ ------ ------ ------ ------
A1     B2     C3     a      x
A1     B2     C3     b      y
A1     B2     C3     c      z
```